# PHP - How would i scan a specific UDP Port to see if my game server is online or not

Tags: php, udp, port

i recently got back into php! I have been trying to get this to work but i just can't seem to get it :(

So, i am trying to check to see if a UDP port (the port i am using for my game server is running or not) it says "Online" but it stays online even when i turn the server off :( can someone explain to me what is going and correct me? thanks!

```
 <?php
$host = '47.39.46.24';
        $port = 14242; 
        $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 7; 
        if($fp = fsockopen("udp://".$host,$port,$errCode,$errStr))
        {
            $write = fwrite($fp,"x00");
            if (!$write)
            { 
            echo 'offline';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'online'; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
           echo 'offline';
        } 
        fclose($fp);
?>
```

And before you say i shouldn't be giving my ip don't worry it isn't real :D

Comment: UPD is connectionless.. the write will always succeed, even if nobody is listening anymore.

Comment: okay, Do you know of any creative ways i could ping or check if my game server is online?

Comment: UDP is fine, but it requires an answer (just like the real ping)

Comment: What? i don't understand

Comment: Imagine you pick up the phone and dial a number... It rings one time, two times, three times.. then you hang up, assuming nobody is at home. You repeat that half an hour later, after the first ring somebody picks up the call... got it?

Comment: You have to read for something, so try a loop where you do an fwrite() followed by an fread() until you either get an answer or reach a timeout